# Form the JSON object - serialization C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
"fields": [
   {
       "field": {
            "name": "SMS",
            "value": "Yes"
       }
   },
   {
       "field": {
            "name": "Email",
            "value": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "field": {
            "name": "Total",
            "value": ""
        }
    },
]
```

I have tried to form the JSON format like above, so i formed the class like below. While serialization it does not return expected form, how can i achieve this one.

```
public class Test
{
    public List<Field> fields;
}
public class Field
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Response:

```
"fields": [{
                "name": "SMS",
                "value": "Yes"
            }, {
                "name": "Email",
                "value": ""
            },{
                "name": "Total",
                "value": ""
            }]
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using http://www.newtonsoft.com/json?

Comment: I can't understand quite clearly. Are you saying that - you had some input string -> serialized to array of objects through JSON.Net -> which on deserialization doesn't give back the original string. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize resulting JSON object with anonymous types and LINQ. Please try this code:

```
var test = new Test {fields = new List<Field>()};
test.fields.Add(new Field {name = "f1", value = "v1"});
test.fields.Add(new Field {name = "f2", value = "v2"});

var json = JObject.FromObject(new { fields = test.fields.Select(f => new {field = f}).ToArray() })
    .ToString();
```

A `json` variable would be:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": {
        "name": "f1",
        "value": "v1"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": {
        "name": "f2",
        "value": "v2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this website http://json2csharp.com and generate all the classes automatically. Just copy-paste your json there.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a class level:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<FieldHolder> fields;
}

public class FieldHolder
{
    public Field field { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```